# itextsharp - CSS not getting applied - C# .NET

Tags: c#, css, .net, itext

I'm using `iTextSharp` for converting a `HTML` page to `PDF`. I'm making use of the helper class given [here](http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/itextsharp-simplify-your-html-to-pdf-creation/) and I've also tried to make use of `StyleSheet.LoadTagStyle()` to apply CSS. But nothing seems to work. Any insights?

**EDIT**

I'm able to add styles like this -

```
.mystyle
{
   color: red;
   width: 400px;
}
```

With the following code -

```
StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
css.LoadStyle("mystyle", "color", "red");
css.LoadStyle("mystyle", "width", "400px");
```

But what happens when I’ve complex styles like this?

```
div .myclass
{
    /*some styles*/
}

td a.hover
{
    /*some styles*/
}

td .myclass2
{
    /*some styles*/
}    
.myclass .myinnerclass
{
    /*some styles*/
}
```

How to add it using iTextSharp?

Comment: Hi,  I am also stuck on the same issue, when i use LoadTagStyle it works perfectly,  I can also get it work for "LoadStyle()" when i use only "color" attribute.  However it does not seem to work when i am trying to use "font-color" or "font-size" attributes.  Any examples where in we can convert css classes

Comment: Use [https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa), you can install it trough nuget. It works with the wkhtmltopdf which uses the webkit engine to render the html/css. It's Awesome! **It supports html/css.**

Comment: Thanks @Preben Huybrechts if you put it in an answer I'd up vote it - this actually better than tinkering with ITextSharp.

Comment: Thanks @PrebenHuybrechts for a workable solution. Who would want to recreate the entire CSS with `LoadTagStyle`..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you're on the right track with using [StyleSheet.LoadTagStyle()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/StyleSheet.html#loadTagStyle%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

basically it's a four step process:

1. get the HTML in a string
2. instantiate a [StyleSheet](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/StyleSheet.html) object and call **StyleSheet.LoadTagStyle()** for each style you want.
3. call [HTMLWorker.ParseToList()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.html#parseToList%28java.io.Reader,%20com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet%29)
4. add the [IElement](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Element.html)(s) returned from above call to the Document object.

here's a simple [HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language='C#' Class='styles' %>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using iTextSharp.text;  
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;  

public class styles : IHttpHandler {
  public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    string Html = @"
<h1>h1</h1>
<p>A paragraph</p>    
<ul> 
<li>one</li>   
<li>two</li>   
<li>three</li>   
</ul>";
    StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H1, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "16");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.P, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "10");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.P, HtmlTags.COLOR, "#ff0000");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.UL, HtmlTags.INDENT, "10");
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.LI, HtmlTags.LEADING, "16");
    using (Document document = new Document()) {
      PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
      document.Open();
      List<IElement> objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
        new StringReader(Html), styles
      );
      foreach (IElement element in objects) {
        document.Add(element);
      }
    }
 }
  public bool IsReusable {
      get { return false; }
  }
}
```

you need version 5.0.6 to run the code above. support for parsing HTML has been greatly improved.

if you want to see what tags are supported by the current version, see the [SVN for the HtmlTags class](https://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/).

Comment: i think you also asked this question on the [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg55976.html)? as noted, you'll either have to wait a while or contact their consultancy team.

Answer (score 3):

```
var reader = new StringReader(text);
var styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "Arial");
styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "size", fontSize + "px");
styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "font-weight", "bold");

ArrayList list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(reader, styles);
for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
{

  var element = (IElement)list[k];

  if (element is Paragraph)
  {
    var paragraph = (Paragraph)element;
    paragraph.SpacingAfter = 10f;
    cell.AddElement(paragraph);
  }
 else
  cell.AddElement((IElement)list[k]);
}
```