# How do I use css and stylesheets with ITextSharp 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, css, itext, stylesheet

I'm exporting an html view to pdf, how can i get it to recognise css styles? mostly colors, table borders, font sizes, nothing too hectic.

Comment: Use [https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa), you can install it trough nuget. It works with the wkhtmltopdf which uses the webkit engine to render the html/css. It's Awesome! **It supports html/css**.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321779/itextsharp-css-not-getting-applied-c-net/5322787#5322787). Support for HTML and CSS is getting better with each version but its still no where near full HTML & CSS support. For instance, I don't believe that HTML classes and ID are supported yet, you can only style tags in general. This is on the iText roadmap but I don't know when they expect to be completed.