# Adding css when creating pdf using itextsharp using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

i am using the below code, to create a pdf and it works fine. I want to add css to the pdf. How can i do it ?

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Clinic-Locator-Information.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            dl_ClinicList.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321779/itextsharp-css-not-getting-applied-c-sharp-net

Comment: @MartinErnst i had a look at that already, they have used html in a string to convert to pdf. But for my case, it is directly from datalist control, So I do not surely know where to set the styles

Comment: It doesn't matter if you render a control as HTML or if you have an HTML string literal, they're the same thing ultimately. Just render the control, dump the HTML, take a look at it and then use the post that @MartinErnst referenced. If you run into any troubles please remember that the `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated for several years now in favor of the `XMLWorker`. I'd recommend that you explore that path because that is where all new features have been added.