# Is it possible to change cell border color in pure classic HTML? (NO CSS)

Tags: html, .net

I am looking for a way to change the color of HTML table's cell(particular td) using HTML ONLY. NO CSS.
Like for examply bgcolor=”#FF0000″ changes the back ground color of td. Is there a way to change color of a cell's border to white. Or make it invisible without using CSS? Just plain simple classic HTML

Comment: there's `bordercolor`, but that's in the `<table>` tag and applies to the entire table. doesn't look like there was ever a per-cell/row border color option.

Comment: That's what I am afraid of. I am using ItextSharp HtmlWorker which does not acknowledges CSS easily.  I wanted to hide border of certain cells. WHat is the easiest way to do so? Any ideas?

Comment: what do you have against CSS?

Comment: have you tried CSS within the HTML Element like <div style="boarder-color:red;"></div>?

Comment: @CS_STEM I did. Doesnt work.

Comment: try this it may help it also may not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321779/itextsharp-css-not-getting-applied-c-sharp-net

Comment: also if you can try JavaScript you can apply styles with JavaScript  document.getElementById("date").style="boarder-color:red"; either way you go you need CSS

Comment: it is not recognizing `HtmlTags` in   `styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H1, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "16");`

And nope javascript not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is nothing in any HTML specification for setting the border color at all, still less on a per-element basis. There is the widely supported nonstandard `bordercolor` attribute, but it works on the table as a whole, setting all border colors in it.

What comes closest to what you are asking is the trick of wrapping the content of the cell in a single-cell table and setting border color on it:

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>foo
  <td><table border=2 rules=none bordercolor=red><tr><td>bar</table>
  <td>more
</table>
```

The style of the border is then browser-dependent, and so is the visual impression of its color, since solid red looks different from outset red. Moreover, the border is really *inside* the table cell, not around it, as you see if you set border on the outer table:

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td>foo
  <td><table border=2 rules=none bordercolor=red><tr><td>bar</table>
  <td>more
</table>
```

Comment: http://snag.gy/A9CtP.jpg
This is what I am trying to make using ItextSharp. I am currently focusing on the middle part this http://snag.gy/qg7dV.jpg
Any idea how I can create this middle part without css? There can be multiple items in the voice (dynamic) so i am guessing they must be in form of tr

Comment: @Arbaaz, I don’t see any specific border color in your .jpg, and I don’t see why you want to create the layout without CSS.

Comment: you see `internet charges bandwith ratio..` and its amount?  that is supposed to be a tr . There can be multile items (tr without border) . I mentioned why I cant use CSS in my previous comments  I am using ItextSharp HtmlWorker which does not acknowledges CSS easily.

Comment: I still don’t see a border, just a background color. Regarding your tools, consider switching to tools that actually help you to get things done.